# Jenkins MultiBranch Pipeline - Automatically apply trigger when branch is detected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline.
I want to detect new branches frequently, but I don't want to trigger build upon detection or anytime there is a change in the branch, instead, I want to do nightly build with detected branches.

I configured the pipeline to suppress automatic SCM triggers
[image]

and added this to the Jenkinsfile

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('H 23 * * *')])
])
```

The problem is that the `pollSCM` config is applied only after the first build of the branch.
So if the multibranch job has detected a new branch, I would have to go and manually start a build for that branch, and only then the `pollSCM` will take effect.

Is there a way to automatically apply the `pollSCM` config upon detecting a branch?

Comment: You may want to trigger a build, determine in your pipeline the reason why the build was triggered, ind if it's not by `cron` then stop it.

Comment: @MaratC Is there a way to prevent the build number from increasing in such case?

Comment: Nope, build numbers are always increasing.

Comment: @MaratC I see. that's what I've done for now